# Insertar Datos desde una tabla a otra con un Procedimiento en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, insert, tablas, cursor

Buen día,
Tengo una tabla llamada AsisteD en SQL Server que contiene, entre otros, los siguientes campos:
Fecha, Empleado, Registro, HoraRegistro.

Donde se registra información de las Asistencias del personal, mostrada de esta forma:
[image: Ejemplo AsisteD]
Siendo el campo Fecha del tipo datetime, Personal varchar, Registro char(10) y HoraRegistro char(5).
Como se puede ver en la imagen, se registran entradas y salidas de los empleados por cada fecha. Cabe mencionar que se puede llegar hasta 6 registros por día, por empleado.

Ahora bien, necesito que estén los datos en una sola fila por Fecha y Empleado, es decir, que por ejemplo Del Empleado 0001 en la fecha 18/Sept/2019 se tenga un solo registro (fila) con todas sus entradas y salidas con sus respectivas horas.

Para ello, creé una tabla distinta como sigue:

```
 CREATE TABLE AsistenciasRep
(
    Fecha datetime,
    Personal char(10),
    Registro1  char(10),
    HoraRegistro1 char(5),
    Registro2  char(10),
    HoraRegistro2 char(5),
    Registro3  char(10),
    HoraRegistro3 char(5),
    Registro4  char(10),
    HoraRegistro4 char(5),
    Registro5  char(10),
    HoraRegistro5 char(5),
    Registro6  char(10),
    HoraRegistro6 char(5),  
)
```

Mi idea inicial era utilizar un Cursor pero he leído que quizás no sea lo más conveniente, por lo que he empezado a hacer un Procedimiento que pueda ejecutar a manera de Job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertarRegistroAsistencias
AS
BEGIN
    --Insertar datos
    WITH RegistroAsistencias AS
    (
       SELECT
          d.FechaD, d.Personal, d.HoraRegistro AS [Hora], d.Registro AS [Registro],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.Personal, d.Fecha 
             ORDER BY CONVERT(time(0), d.HoraRegistro)) AS [Fila],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.Personal, d.Fecha 
             ORDER BY d.Registro) AS [Fila2]
       FROM AsisteD d    
    )
    INSERT INTO AsistenciasRep
     (Fecha, Personal, Registro1, HoraRegistro1, Registro2, HoraRegistro2, Registro3, HoraRegistro3, Registro4, HoraRegistro4, Registro5, HoraRegistro5, Registro6, HoraRegistro6)
    SELECT
       r.FechaD, r.Personal,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila2 = 1 THEN r.Registro END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila = 1 THEN r.Hora END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila2 = 2 THEN r.Registro END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila = 2 THEN r.Hora END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila2 = 3 THEN r.Registro END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila = 3 THEN r.Hora END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila2 = 4 THEN r.Registro END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila = 4 THEN r.Hora END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila2 = 5 THEN r.Registro END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila = 5 THEN r.Hora END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila2 = 6 THEN r.Registro END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.Fila = 6 THEN r.Hora END)
    FROM
       RegistroAsistencias r
    WHERE
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AsistenciasRep
                    WHERE (r.Personal = Personal) AND (r.FechaD = Fecha))
    GROUP BY
       r.Personal, r.FechaD;
END
GO
```

La cosa es:

1.- No estoy segura que la manera en que lo estoy haciendo sea lo mejor ya que hasta warnings me da relacionado a NULLS (que eso igual tenga que ver con si algún empleado no tiene los 6 registros, no son obligatorios 6, simplemente ese es el tope).

2.- Me hace falta algo para asegurarme de que no se inserten valores repetidos, es decir, si ya hay un registro (fila) de cierto empleado en cierta fecha, que no lo vuelva a insertar o en dado caso no sé si sería mejor que borre y vuelva a insertar...

En fin, que si hay una manera mejor de hacer esto, estoy abierta a otras opciones, muchas gracias.

Comment: Realmente el código está bastante bien, pero debes usar un solo ROW_NUMBER para que no te combine los registros, te recomiendo el que tiene orden por hora. No creo que sea buena idea guardar los datos con ese diseño de tabla, a excepción de casos muy específicos. Lo ideal es mantener la consulta y la tabla original (para más detalles, lee acerca de la normalización de tablas).